# Re-captcha v3 integration

Tags: javascript, captcha

I'm trying to integrate [reCaptcha V3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)

what I tried is:

```
<script defer="defer"
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&amp;render=6Lda2XgUAAAAAKxRqwe9zBL09zv2ja1DYV-r">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function(){
        grecaptcha.execute('6Lda2XgUAAAAAKxRaqwev2ja1DYV-r', {action: '/foo/bar/'}).then(function(token) {
            alert(token)
        });
    };
</script>
```

But on loading page I get `(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) null` Does somebody know the reason and how could i fix it?

EDIT: I catched this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: grecaptcha.execute(...).then(...).catch is not a function
    at onloadCallback ((index):18)
    at gf (recaptcha__pl.js:512)
    at Gj (recaptcha__pl.js:508)
    at recaptcha__pl.js:520
    at recaptcha__pl.js:539
onloadCallback @ (index):18
gf @ recaptcha__pl.js:512
Gj @ recaptcha__pl.js:508
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__pl.js:520
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__pl.js:539
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) null
```

Answer (score 3):

grecaptcha.execute is created in the first script

the defer attribute will wait for page to load before executing it.

So removing the defer should make it.

Note: defer is not appearing in the official integration documentation

Comment: I don't have defer in my script tag. Here's what mine looks like: `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=myrecaptchakey"></script>`